# How do I make HTML working in HighChart title?

Tags: highcharts

I want to use HTML in high chart titles. Something like:

```
{
   "title": "An <b>Important</b> Chart"
}
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `useHtml: true` like that :

```
...
title: {
    text: 'An <b>Important</b> Chart',
    useHtml: true
},
...
```

[Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.useHTML) - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/27Lmayef/)